# Is there an orthogonal time dimension in Minkowski spacetime?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime

Space dimensions are orthogonal one to each other. But what about time in the Minkowski diagram?

At first sight, time seems to be orthogonal to space. But we have to consider that each Minkowski diagram is an observer's diagram. Thus, an object that is not moving with regard to the observer will describe a vertical worldline in the Minkowski diagram of the observer. However, from the point of view of another observer (inertial frame) the worldline described by the object might be inclined. Even the worldline of the observer himself which is the y-axis might be sloped from the point of view of other observers.

The conclusion seems to be that time is not orthogonal to space. Or is there an error?

Comment: Time is orthogonal to space dimensions in drawings only. In real life, when you accelerate in your car its tires do not draw a curve on the asphalt. If the car leaves marks, they are just straight lines. Because time is not like other dimensions, and when you draw it as orthogonal it's only in order to visualize the change (of velocity for instance) better.

Comment: These are just equations - no less no more. And time dilatation and distance contraction that result from them contradict the constancy of light. If Δx′=Δx/γ and Δt′=γΔt then c=x/t and c=x'/t' cannot be both correct. Because time and distance change under transforms in inverse proportions (if t'>t then x'<x), while the above requires that x/t=x'/t' which means direct proportions. These are the traps of mathematics applied to physics without real understanding of the problem. Therefore your equations prove nothing.

Comment: @brightmagus: I do not agree with you that there is no orthogonality at all, because for the observer there is true orthogonality in his own Minkowki diagram.

Comment: @neuneck: What you are saying is that time is orthogonal from an observer's point of view, but not in an objective, universal sense. Each time when I am stating that time is orthogonal I must admit that this is a very relative statement, and that the application of any Lorentz boost may invalidate it.

The rotation formulas you mentioned are characteristic for orthogonal systems, and rotations do not harm orthogonality.

Comment: @brightmagus If you think about it carefully, you will see that multiplying time with $\gamma < 1$ represents time dilation, while multiplying spatial coordinates with $\gamma < 1$ represents length contraction. The wikipedia, me and SR are saying the same thing.

Comment: @Moonraker Time is orthogonal from *every* observer's point of view. Observe that there is no $t'$ dependence in $x'$, even after the transformation. It is just that going from one observer to the other will mix time and space.

Comment: @Neuneck: But which wikipedia, yours or mine? :) According to your equations, if you multiply 1 second by 1,5 you will get 1,5 seconds, that means longer (dilated) time for the primed frame of reference. If you multiply 1 meter by 1,5 you will get 1,5 meters, which again means longer (dilated) distance for the primed frame. So you get no distance contraction for the primed ref. frame (where the time dilatation is recorded).

Comment: @brightmagus did you even read the article you linked to? They state the formula for time dilation is valid for the system with the moving clock, while length contraction is *with respect to* its rest frame. I retract my comment above, where I admit I was too quick with the $\gamma$ on $\delta x$, but keep my conceptual point.

Comment: x is just x in the rest frame of the moving object. It's the "stationary" observer that records length (distance) contraction **as compared to the moving one**. The same goes for time. t is just t for the moving observer himself, and yet it is the stationary observer that records dilation. Therefore time-dilatation and distance-contraction are phenomena observed from the frame dubbed "stationary". These are the conclusions of SR supported by the equations I presented.

Comment: @Moonraker: "because for the observer there is true orthogonality in his own Minkowki diagram". Have you ever seen "your own Minkowski diagram" other than on a piece of paper or on a computer screen? :). It's just a visualization, that's all.

Comment: @bright magus: it is not just a piece of paper! If in your own observer's spacetime two years are passing, these two years are your proper time, which is equal to the spacetime interval of your worldline. But your spacetime interval is constant, and it is recognized by all other observers. Thus, orthogonality of your own spacetime is not only a piece of paper, but objective reality.

Comment: @Moonraker: This is no proof at all. All other observers will recognize my local (proper) time if they just use correct Lorentz transform, without drawings or space-time concepts presenting time as orthogonal. All you need in order to be able to recognize local time is the assumption (axiom) that local time is the same in all inertial frames and that light is constant for all frames. Time orthogonality has nothing to do with it. It's simply redundant for the purpose of recognizing local time.

Comment: Just to point out that the 'slanting' of the t axis happens in Galileian Relativity, too. So, it has nothing to do with Minkowski spacetime, in particular. It's just a convenient way to depict the relationship between two inertial observers in motion wrt one another. Would you talk about non-orthogonality of time in that context?

Comment: Are you asking me? If so than yes, I absolutely agree with what you said: "It's just a convenient way of depicting ....". (And I said exactly the same thing with different wording above.) But obviously saying that we can conveniently **depict** time as orthogonal is not identical to saying that time **is** orthogonal.

Comment: @brightmagus, my comment was for the OP. I just wanted to stress the fact that the apparent 'slanting of the temporal axis' is just a pictorial aid that shows up in Newtonian mechanics as well, that is in a context where space and time are absolute and completely separate from each other.

Comment: @Peltio: Sure :)

Answer (score 7):

Time *is* orthogonal to space. Check that $(1, 0, 0, 0) \cdot (0, 1, 0, 0) = 0$ and likewise for all other spacelike unit vectors, where $\cdot$ represents the Lorentz invariant scalar product and I put time in the 0th coordinate.

The inclination originates in the Lorentz transformation that you use to go from one observer's point of view to another one's. Perfoming a boost creates an $x$ dependence in $t'$ and a $t$ dependence in $x'$:
$$ t' = \gamma \left(t - \frac{v}{c^2} x\right), x' = \gamma (x - v t)$$

This also happens in regular euclidean space, e.g. when perfoming a rotation about the $z$ axis, giving
$$ x' = \cos\theta \ x - \sin\theta\  y,\quad y' = \sin\theta\ x + \cos\theta\ y$$
So after a rotation a previousely vertical line will look inclined as well.

Edit: Observe that there is no t′ dependence in x′, even after the transformation. So, while time is *always* orthogonal to space, an object at rest for observer $O$ (say the observer's nose) will not be at rest for an observer $O'$ that moves away from observer $O$ at a speed $v \neq 0$.

Comment: In your formulas t' and x' are depending on v, the relative velocity of the observer which is depending on t and x, and the 2 formulas of dependence you mention are not the same. By consequence, as long as v=0, there may be (and there is) orthogonality. But as soon as v >0 orthogonality disappears.

Comment: @Moonraker $\vec{t}=(1,0,0,0)$ is orthogonal to $\vec{x}=(0,1,0,0)$, and $\vec{t}'=(\gamma t,-\gamma v,0,0)$ is orthogonal to $\vec{x}'=(-\gamma v,\gamma,0,0)$. Sure $\vec{t}'$ is not orthogonal to $\vec{x}$, but that's not a particularly interesting comparison, since those are basis vectors drawn from different coordinate systems.

Comment: @Chris White: I agree. But that means that orthogonality is relative. If an object is moving in 3D space any observer will agree that the 3D space the object is moving in is orthogonal. This absolute vision does apparently not exist in 4D-spacetime.

Comment: @Moonraker I think we're talking cross purposes. Realize that I could take normal Newtonian 3D space and describe it with a non-orthogonal coordinate system too. There is no sense in which Newtonian space is more orthogonal than Minkowski spacetime, because orthogonality is not a property of the vector space but rather it is a relation between two specific vectors.

Comment: @Moonraker also note that Lorentz transformations will keep orthogonality between purely spacelike vectors intact (actually even between fully general four-vectors), i.e. if $ x \cdot y = 0 \Leftrightarrow x' \cdot  y' = 0$! Therefore "orthogonality" is observer independent, since if one observer finds two **four-vectors** to be orthogonal, all other observers will find them to be orthogonal in their own coordinate systems as well.

Comment: @ChrisWhite, I think your comment should be an answer - an answer that, in fact, I was just about to write.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I have no objection to you writing such an answer :)

Comment: @ChrisWhite, too late! - I've already jumped in the pool and consumed a libation or three.

Answer (score 0):

Any timelike vector has a 3-dimensional subspace orthogonal to it, orthogonal under the Minkowski inner product.  Such a subspace is spanned by vectors that are spacelike under the inner product, and all linear combinations of those vectors are spacelike.

Any timelike vector might be the direction a massive object follows at some point on its worldline.  The 3-dimensional subspace orthogonal to that four-velocity is what an observer following that trajectory would instantaneously consider "space".

An observer's "time" is always orthogonal to his "space", and further, all observers would agree that that is so.